# Shared scope directives with a ngModel in the template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

Having something like:

```
module.directive('myCustomInput', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<input ng-model="$scope.myVar"></input>'
        }
}
```

This does not bind to the model, the only way I can make it to work is by specifying a variable in the scope: {}, and then use it, which is what actually I don't want.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mention `$scope` in view

Try like this

```
<input ng-model="myVar"></input>
```